# How this converters can not work?

Tags: pandas

The code as below:
I try to use read_excel and want to apply multiplication to one column, so I use converters, but it doesn't work, the column didn't change.
If I use the wrong way?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_excel('Energy Indicators.xls',sheetname='Energy', header=1, skiprows=16, skip_footer=38, index_col=None, names=['Country','Energy Supply', 'Energy Supply per Capita', '% Renewable'], parse_cols='C,D,E,F', converters = {'Energy Supply': (lambda x: x*1000000)})
```

Comment: what's the dtype of your column in the df once loaded?

Comment: Hi Boud, it shows object (I use df.dtypes)

Comment: It could be your column has more than just float and is not converted to that type, thus the lambda doesn't apply.